# VSCode: How do I KEEP blank lines (in scss files or others)?

Tags: css, sass, styles, visual-studio-code

VSCode deletes empty lines by default in certain cases, but what if I want to preserve/keep blank/empty lines in a document? For example, in my .scss file, I want to keep the blank lines that I made in between nested styles within a parent between properties and children, but "Format Document" keeps removing them. How can I tell VSCode to not remove any blank lines that I make? It seems to keep them for other file types.

Comment: @klewis Sorry, not sure what you mean. The point of my question is that I DON'T want to remove blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, in my .scss file, I want to keep the blank lines that I made in between nested styles

You can tryout the extension **Beautify**

- Download it through VSCode's Extensions Manager.
- Once installed, from the top menu select Go -> Go to File...
- In the command line type, `>b`
- You should then see an command for `Beautify File`
- Click it.  It should format your opened .SCSS file and preserve the blank spaces between each CSS rule set (if they were there already).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in scss file and solved it by disabling 'prettier' extension, so it stopped to remove blank lines.